# Spring ServletRegistrationBean not loaded in JUnit Test

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, junit

I'm trying to test a Rest Service in my Spring Boot Application.
I can do ir successfully when I run or debug the whole application. Spring Bott start shows the following lines, among others:

```
2015-07-02 17:04:10.654  INFO 3084 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
2015-07-02 17:04:10.769  INFO 3084 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-07-02 17:04:10.769  INFO 3084 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2449 ms
2015-07-02 17:04:11.219  INFO 3084 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2015-07-02 17:04:11.224  INFO 3084 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2015-07-02 17:04:11.224  INFO 3084 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
```

However, when I run my JUnit test, everything works fine, request mappings work, etc, except that the servlet is not initialized. Indeed, those lines above do not appear.

That's strange, because I'm running the test using the same Application.class which I use to run the whole application. This is Application.class:

```
@ImportResource("classpath:/META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-context.xml")
@SpringBootApplication
@WebAppConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And from my JUnit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class CatalogRestControllerTests extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
...
@Test
public void someTest() {...}
}
```

I've been trying to fix the problem from servlet-context.xml and web.xml configuration files. But I don't think the problem is there, since it works for Application.class

Any idea?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

So it seems I was missing **@WebIntegrationTest** annotation on my JUnit class. This is what documentation says about **@WebIntegrationTest**:

> Test class annotation signifying that the tests are "web integration
>   tests" and therefore require full startup in the same way as a
>   production application (listening on normal ports). Normally used in
>   conjunction with @SpringApplicationConfiguration,
>
> This annotation can be used as an alternative to @IntegrationTest and
>   @WebAppConfiguration.